# How to draw rectangle on Buttons by using canvas

Tags: android, draw, ontouchlistener

I have 3 LinerLayouts inside a RelativeLayout, each LinerLayouts contain 9 Buttons.
Now i want to draw rectangle boxe on top of Buttons whenever i touch the buttons and that rectangle box should slide(move) to each button how the finger is moving. Any idea how to do this.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(mRect, new Paint());
}

private Rect mRect = new Rect();

private static final int WIDTH = 100;
private static final int HEIGHT = 100;

private void setRectPosition(int x, int y) {
    mRect.set(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    setRectPosition((int)x, (int)y);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I think this can worked.

Comment: thanks for your response Changwei Yao, but if i touch one button (not clicking) and keep on moving finger to next buttons the box should also move accordingly, by using onClicklistener() i can't do this, i want something like onTouchEvent(). In onTouchEvent we can get x any y  co ordinates values, by using that we can draw. but here how we can?

Comment: You should set the width and height your self. Implement this in Your RelativeLayout or LinearLayout depned on your scenario

Comment: All buttons and liner Layouts are in one relative layout and that xml i'm inflating, so how can i draw rectangles in this case.